# How to put single quote and double quote in post filename

Tags: yaml

Is it possible to use special characters like single and double quote in yml front matter

Comment: Can you provide an usage example and what error is currently giving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post file name are used to represent the link to the post, so having a file `my-post.md` will result in `/my-post` link. Putting quotes there is a bad idea - quotes in the link will be html encoded - so link won't look nice, and it will make your life harder dealing with files with quotes.
I assume you're missing the [yml front matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/) feature - you can name your file with a simple name, but have a `title` in your post with any character you want:

```
---
title: W'ha"t e!veR T?<tle@# y04 w4nt
---
```

Answer (score 0):

If I use double quote I need to use `>` in title like

```
title: >
    A winter's "day"
```